# how u maintain a static menu bar in gwt using mvp framework

Tags: gwt-mvp

I would love to know from anyone who knows how we can keep the a widget in mvp static by putting it in the entry point class.Or is it recommended to include the widget in appcontroller.

I have an issue like I want to make my menu bar static throughout my page. For this I follow

1. I will create a RootPanel
2. I divide the page into two by adding two panels.I would like to send the mainpanel to the Appcontroller by goTo and change the main panel with respect to the click in the menu bar.
3. Here i am confused like where should I add my menu bar to handle its events.
   Can anyone help me out with this